# JAVA Variable declaration not allowed here

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, int, declaration

I get an error "Variable declaration not allowed here" and I don't know why, I'm new in java and can't find answer :/
As it says, I can't make "int" in "if" but is there a way to create it?

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;import java.util.Scanner;
 public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File plik = new File("test.txt");
    PrintWriter saver = new PrintWriter("test.txt");

     int score = 0;
     System.out.println("Q: What's bigger");
     System.out.println("A: Dog B: Ant");
     Scanner odp = new Scanner(System.in);
     string odpo = odp.nextLine();

     if(odpo.equals("a"))
        int score = 1;
     else
         System.out.println("Wrong answer");

  }
}
```

Comment: With `int score = 1;` you are trying to redeclare `score` variable. Try without `int` part.

Comment: inside the if statement, change  int score = 1; to   score = 1;

Comment: It is interesting to note that the declaration is not objected by IntelliJ if it is surrounded by flower braces like: 
```if(x > y) {int i=1;}``` 
While it is objected and error is spit if the curly braces are removed: 
```if(x>y) int i=1;```
Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` must be changed to `String`.

By writing `int score` you're trying to declare a new variable that already exists, which you declared before already. Just remove the `int` part and you will get the assignment you want.

Answer (score 20):

As per Java spec, You cannot declare a local variable when there is no scope. While declaring `int score = 1` in if, there is no scope. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html

> A local variable, one of the following
>   *A local variable declared in a block
>   *A local variable declared in a for statement

Also you have already declared a variable named `score` above. Even if you remove that declaration, you'll get the error because of the above reason.

Answer (score 5):

Change `int score = 1;` to `score = 1;`.

#### Explanation:

To declare variable we use

```
someType variable;
```

To assign (or change) value to variable we use

```
variable = value;
```

We can mix these instruction into one line like;

```
someType variable = value;
```

So when you do

```
int score = 1;
```

you first declare variable `score` and then assign `1` to it.

Problem here is that we can't have two (or more) local variables with same name in same scope. So something like

```
int x = 1;
int x = 2;
System.out.println(x)
```

is incorrect because we can't decide which `x` we should use here.

Same about

```
int x = 1;
{
    int x = 2;
    System.out.println(x)
}
```

So if you simply want to change value of already created variable use only assignment, don't include declaration part (remove type information)

```
int x = 1;
//..
x = 2;//change value of x to 2
```

---

Now it is time for confusing part - scope. You need to understand that variable have some are in which they can be used. This area is called scope, and is marked with `{` `}` brackets which surrounds declaration of variable. So if you create variable like

```
{
    int x = 1;
    System.out.println(x); //we can use x here since we are in its scope 
}
System.out.println(x); //we are outside of x scope, so we can't use it here

int x = 2;
System.out.println(x); //but now we have new x variable, so it is OK to use it
```

So because of that scope limitation declarations in places like

```
if (condition)
    int variable = 2;
else
    int variable = 3;
```

are incorrect because such code is equal to

```
if (condition){
    int variable = 2;
}else{
    int variable = 3;
}
```

so this variable couldn't be accessible anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget brackets, "*JAVA Variable declaration not allowed here*" might also occur. This is because a variable needs to be declared with a clear scope.

In my case, ****I forgot a bracket around my OUTER** - for loop inside the method** which gave me the same error. [image]

```
public static void InsertionSort(int[] list){
        for (int i = 1 ; i < list.length ; i++)

            double currentValue = list[i];
            int k;
            for (k = i - 1 ; k >= 0 && list[k] > currentValue ; k--){

                list[k+1] = list[k];
            }

            // Insert the current element
            list[k+1] = currentValue;

        System.out.println("The sorted array is : "+Arrays.toString(list));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Java spec, You cannot declare a local variable when there is no scope.

So because of that scope limitation declarations in places like

```
if (condition)
    int variable = 2;
else
    int variable = 3;
```

are incorrect because such code is equal to

```
if (condition){
    int variable = 2;
}else{
    int variable = 3;
}
```

so this variable will not be accessible from anywhere.