# Variable declaration not allowed. But there is no scope overlap

Tags: java, scope

When I fill an array of characters I get an error.

```
     List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
     int i = 0;
     if (i == 0) {
         Character str = 'a';
         letters.add(str);
     } else if (i == 1)
         Character str = 'b'; //Variable declaration not allowed here
         letters.add(str);
     }
```

Why does this error message appear? Cases i==0 and i==1 are mutually 
exclusive. Why compiler doesn't allow me to decare str the second time?

Comment: You're missing `{` after your `else if`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a **simple typographical error**

Comment: I am voting to keep it because the error message is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230722/java-variable-declaration-not-allowed-here (not yet closed), but the cause is very different.

Comment: Why does you creat "str" variable every if block. Create once and initialize it every time you need it. Creating new vars takes more resources.

Comment: I try to keep a scope of my variable smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope in not overlapping, this is correct. You are forgetting an opening curly bracket at `else if` line. This is just a typo that looks like

`} else if (i == 1){` fixes a problem.

Your situation is distinctly different from [JAVA Variable declaration not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230722/java-variable-declaration-not-allowed-here)